# Command of button dont work,button inside collection View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

i have a problem when try to call a command by clicking a button, this is my code, help please
Postscript, if I put the button off the collectionView, the command work.
the command's name is **ButtonCommand** , i think i need more parameters, help.

> MaingPage.Xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="XamarinCollectionView.MainPage"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PruebaAppMap.ViewModels"
         xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:PruebaAppMap.Models"
         x:DataType="viewModels:MainPageViewModel"
         BackgroundColor="#2471A3">

<CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="Models:Product">
            <Frame
                Padding="5"
                CornerRadius="5"
                IsClippedToBounds="False">
                <Grid HeightRequest="100">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height=".7*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding Price,StringFormat='{0:C}'}"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" x:DataType="viewModels:MainPageViewModel"  Text="Click me!" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
                </Grid>

            </Frame>

        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

> View Model --MainPageViewModel

```
namespace PruebaAppMap.ViewModels{

public class MainPageViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public MainPageViewModel() 
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Name="Yogurt",
                Price=5.50m,
                Image="yogurt.png",
                hasOffer=false

            },              

        };
        ButtonCommand = new Command(async () => await buton());
    }
    public async Task buton()
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Button pressed", "button was pressed", "ok");
    }}
}
```

Comment: the BindingContext for the elements inside the DataTemplate is an instance of Product.  `ButtonCommand` is not defined for Product.

Comment: I've never done anything with Xamarin, but in WPF you'd do something like `Command="{Binding ButtonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPage}}"`. Something similar might work here.

Comment: i´m new in xamarin, don´t know how to do

Comment: there are many examples that will show you how to reference alternate sources in bindings

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: jack Hua, thanks a lot, you´re the best.....your answer work for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jason said, the `BindingContext` for the button inside the DataTemplate is an instance of `Product`. `ButtonCommand` is not defined for Product. ButtonCommand is in your ViewModel, so you need to reference `ViewModel.ButtonCommand`:

First, give a name to your ContentPage, lets say it `MyPage`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"

             x:Name="MyPage"

             x:Class="App266.MainPage">
```

In your binding:

```
<Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Click me!" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ButtonCommand, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
```

BTW, there is no need to write `x:DataType`.

Refer: [Xamarin Button Command (inside of ListView.ItemTemplate) Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332349/xamarin-button-command-inside-of-listview-itemtemplate-not-firing)